# How to add more param to Serialization Model for using at to_presentation

Tags: python, django

Here is my so

```
class DataFieldSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = DataField
        fields = ["field", "topic", "category", "group", "alias", "units"]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.extra_param = kwargs.pop('extra_param', None)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        data = super().to_representation(instance)
        print("Extra Param:", self.extra_param)
```

This is how I call the `DataFieldSerializer`

```
result_data = DataFieldWithUnitsSerializer(data_fields, many=True, extra_param='example').data
```

When I run the code I got this result

```
Extra Param:None
```

I guess it is not the right way to add more param into a model serializer.

To sum up, I want to find away to pass an extra param to the Serializer Model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way is to send by [`context`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context), like this:

```
#serializer
class DataFieldSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = DataField
        fields = ["field", "topic", "category", "group", "alias", "units"]

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        data = super().to_representation(instance)
        print("Extra Param:", self.context.get('extra_param'))

# usage
result_data = DataFieldWithUnitsSerializer(data_fields, many=True, context= {'extra_param': 'example'}).data
```